# jquery previewfrom multi thumb image

Tags: jquery

Is there a way i can make mouse over image preview like youtube of many thumbs which are placed in single image.See image below.
I know normaly t is done by rotating many images,but in my sample I have this one image with many thumbs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what do you want. It might be way easier to have different images for the thumbnails. 
If you have a big image you could use css sprites 
[Css-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

The idea is have several li elements and put the big image as background and then change each li background position

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul         {padding: 0px; width: 640px;}
    ul li      {display: none; x:inline-block; width: 246px; height: 134px; margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px; 
                border: 1px solid #000; cursor: pointer;
        background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FjvI.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        opacity: 0.5;
        xbackground-position: -9px -79px;

    }
    ul li:first-child{
        display: inline-block;

    }
    ul li:hover{
        opacity:1;
    }
    .thumb0{
        background-position: -9px -79px;

    }
</style>
<script>
alto = 134;
ancho = 246;
x= -9;
y= -79;
i=-1;
for (mx=0; mx < 4; mx++){    
    for (my=0; my < 4; my++){
        i++;
        jQuery('ul li').eq(i).css('background-position-x','-' + ((my * ancho) + 25) + 'px');
        jQuery('ul li').eq(i).css('background-position-y','-' + ((mx * alto) + y*-1)   + 'px');        
    }
}
clok = 0;
ani = function(){
clearTimeout(clok);
    d= jQuery('ul li:visible').next();
    if (d.length !=0){
        jQuery('ul li:visible').hide();
        jQuery(d).show();
    } else {
        jQuery('ul li').hide();
        jQuery('ul li:first-child').show();
    }
    setTimeout(function(){ani()},700);
}
ani();
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/3Zc4g/17/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would use a single image with thumbnails. Can't you splice the thumbnails from the image and use those?

I made a jsfiddle, where you can place that single image as a background in the `<UL>` element, then the `<li>` elements would contain the hover actions for whatever image you wanted to change to.

http://jsfiddle.net/86xCH/7/